# What are the effects if I remove derby.jar from my JDK folder?

Tags: java, derby

I am not using derby db anywhere in my application.Is derby.jar used while connecting to databases like mysql,mssql etc. In what cases does java use derby.jar? What will fail on removal of derby.jar from JDK folder ?

derby.jar is having security issues when I use JAVA1.8.0_172. How to get rid of the same ? Is it fine to change bits of only derby in JDK folder ?

Comment: Why do you want to remove it?

Comment: What security issues are you worried about? I can't see any obvious problems in removing it if you're never going to use it anywhere, but it seems like your reasons for removing it may be misplaced.

Answer (score 1):

The "derby.jar" file provides an easy to use embedded database system that is distributed as part of (some) Java releases.  It is also called "Java DB"; see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html

If you remove it from your JRE, then applications that require it won't work.  That is it.

When you say that "derby.jar" is "having security issues", that would seem to imply that you / your application is *using* Java DB.  If that is that case, and you remove it, that would be a problem.  On the other hand, if the "security issue" is that some security scanner or AV product (merely) flagged the file as possibly infected, then removing it may not additional problems ...

Comment: by the term "having security issues", i meant that a securityscan ran showed us that derby.jar had security issues. I am eager to know if any normal java commands internally uses derby.jar for its execution or while connecting to other databases like mssql,mysql,oracle etc.

Thanks for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: I would first contact the vendor of your security scanner to find out if this is a false positive.

Answer (score 1):

The `derby.jar` is for [Java DB](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/getstart/index.html) which is just Derby with a new name.

If nothing is using Java DB, then removing the jar wouldn't cause any problems. I'm not aware of any internal components that would use it, but it's still part of the JDK and removing it would not be a very good solution.

If you know the [security issues](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/DERBY/issues/DERBY-6858), you should check if there are fixes for newer versions of the JDK and update to that.

Finally, even if Derby has security issues it's unlikely that there's an attack vector based on just the existence of the jar. You would have to be using it for there to be even a possibility for attack.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments.
java1.8.0_172 is the latest version of java available with java8.
It uses derby.jar of version 10.11.1.1 and blackduck security scan is showing a risk with derby.jar with it.

Comment: Well I wouldn't start deleting parts of the JDK no matter how many ducks were telling me there are risks.